# Did any major European country stay neutral during the Napoleonic Wars?

Tags: europe, 19th-century, napoleonic-wars

During World Wars I and II, many countries managed to stay neutral, like Spain and Switzerland. Was there any major country (e.g. not a city-state or a micronation) that did the same during the Napoleonic Wars?

Comment: It would be helpful if you expanded upon what you mean by "major country" beyond just excluding city-states, and micronations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just performed some [Google search](https://www.google.pl/search?q=map+of+europe+in+napoleonic+wars&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=H77bUci4PMHAtQay14CgAQ&ved=0CC4QsAQ&biw=1874&bih=904) that gave me the map of Europe during Napoleonic wars.

Here goes the reproduction from Wikipedia:

[image]

<sup>See the image in other resolutions here: [Europe 1812 map en.png](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Europe_1812_map_en.png)</sup>

So, in Europe, in 1812, there were the following countries:

1. Great Britain - fought
2. Portugal - fought
3. Spain - fought
4. Papal States - fought
5. Kingdom of Naples - fought
6. German States - if treated as a whole (Confederation of the Rhine), fought
7. Austria - fought
8. Denmark + Norway - fought
9. Switzerland - fought
10. Prussia - fought
11. Sweden - fought
12. Duchy of Warsaw - fought
13. Ottoman Empire - fought
14. Russia - fought
15. Holland - fought

I think doing just simple googling would help.

Please remember that Napoleonic Wars was not one war and countries (except Great Britain) did not fight in each of them.

Comment: Balearic Islands are colored on the European Map - why? They were NOT occupied by Napoleon.

Comment: @OlePetersen I don't know, it was the very first map I had taken from Google, and this was 4 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

No major European country stayed neutral (for the whole time of Napoleonic wars).

<strike>The Ottoman Empire (partly placed in Europe, although not traditionally considered a European country) possibly comes closest. But it was by no means the boring Swiss-style neutrality, so I would review the Napoleon's Egyptian campaign, the Russo-Ottoman War of 1806-1812, and the 1807 British naval intervention to get the full story.</strike>

Source:  http://books.google.com/books?id=cG6JC_E1Rf8C&pg=PA269 
combined with http://books.google.pl/books?id=h_TguykH1qcC&pg=PA8 to rule out Kingdom of Sardinia; combined with http://books.google.pl/books?id=QjzYdCxumFcC&pg=PA223 for Ottoman Empire.

Update: Ottoman Empire was in a war with France [until 1802](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Paris_%281802%29).

Comment: I was also thinking about the Ottoman Empire, but she could be also considered as a belligerent during the Egypt Campaign.

Comment: @Voitcus True, they were in a war until http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Paris_(1802)